# Cornerstone / SVN: where does it store its control files?

Tags: svn, cornerstone

I botched creating a Working Directory using Cornerstone for macOS. The WD is in the wrong place. When I try to delete it, it will actually delete it from the master repository, which is a catastrophe. I did some limited tests on files for which I had backup copies.

The Cornerstone Delete command is not working correctly because the creation of the WD was aborted before it completed, so I imagine the configuration info. was not written correctly, if at all.

I just want to start from scratch. If I could pinpoint where Cornerstone stores its control files and configuration information, I could delete them and start with a clean slate.

Does anyone know where Cornerstone hides this stuff? I don't see any ".SVN" directories like with Tortoise/Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: there is indeed a ".SVN" directory, Finder doesn't show it (I'm a macOS newbie). Open a Terminal window, voilà there is the .SVN directory. Just `-rm` it away, and start afresh!